# PHP connection to MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to connect my PHP webpage with my MS SQL database. I've got this code from the internet, but have tried others. All seems to come back with a problem with "mssql_connect".

I have tried (I think) everything and can not find out why it won't work.

My code is:

```
<?php
$myServer = 'SQL5008.Smarterasp.net,1433';
$myUser = '*****';
$myPass = '*****';
$myDB = '*****'; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myuser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT id ";
$query .= "FROM tblEmployees ";
$query .= "WHERE CompanyID=3"; 

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result); 
echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>"; 

//display the results 
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<li>" . $row["id"] . $row["name"] . $row["year"] . "</li>";
}
//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: Try removing single quotes $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myuser, $myPass)

Comment: Sorry, I had tried to put in the connection string in as text. I'll edit my code and remove them. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try using PDO. I use it with SQL SERVER daily. You will need the php sqlsrv extenstion though.

```js
// instantiate the pdo object
try {
    $Server = "localhost";
    $User = "username";
    $Pass = "password";
    $Database = "mydb";
  
    $this->conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$Server;Database=$Database", $User, $Pass);
    $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);//allow for SQL query errors
    }
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
    }
```

Comment: I'm using a php webpage and my database is hosted online. How can I get an extension?

Answer (score 0):

Check using [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) if mssql extension is loaded. According to PHP Manual:

> This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.

If you find out mssql is unloaded, try to connect using sqlsrv extension. Here you can find a few examples http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Anyway it's a good idea to post here an error message you get from PHP.